# Move to latest OGL without using GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm developing on a netbook which fully supports GL < 2 only. It's all working with over 100fps. But since I read that the state machine is deprecated, I'm trying to move, but it seems to be impossible. A lot of functions are not declared using the latest glext.h. So I can't create a shader programm or at least a VBO. So I try to just move the matrices using glm. But send a matrix from glm to ogl is made by calling glUniformMatrix*v, which is not declared here too. So is there a way to "upgrade" without using GLSL?
I don't need any hints that I just include GLSL because it's good and fast etc. because I can't use it and I can't believe it's impossible without it.

I checked the extensions with OpenGL Extension Viewer 3. The report says:
1.1 100%
1.2 100%
1.3 100%
1.4 100%
1.5 66% (unsupported: GL_ARB_occlusion_query)
2.0 10% (supported only: GL_EXT_stencil_two_side)
2.X 0%
3.X 0%
4.X 0%

Comment: Show me the spec for OpenGL ***2.2***.

Comment: @genpfault sorry I messed up with the numbers. Edited and added the log.

Answer (score 6):

> …which fully supports GL <= 2.2 only. (…) But since I read that the state machine is deprecated, I'm trying to move, but it seems to be impossible.

First off: The state machine is not deprecated. The fixed function pipeline has been deprecated. But this change applies only to OpenGL-3 core and further. So if you're limited to OpenGL-2, then fixed function and all that jazz is still available.

> So is there a way to "upgrade" without using GLSL?

You do realize that deprecating the fixed function pipeline means about the same: Everything happens with shaders now. Shaders that are written in GLSL.

GLSL is available in OpenGL-2 as well. It's just not mandatory.

> A lot of functions are not declared using the latest glext.h. So I can't create a shader programm or at least a VBO.

It's not just glext.h you need. You also need some code that loads advanced functions from the OpenGL implementation. A popular choice for this is GLEW, available at http://glew.sourceforge.net

> I can't use it

Well, not out of the box. But using GLEW is a cakewalk:

1. Download GLEW
2. Install into additionaly installed library and include directories
3. Replace all occurances of `#include <GL/gl.h>` with `#include <GL/glew.h>`
4. Add glew32.lib as library dependency to your linker settings
5. Add a call to `glewInit();` right after each OpenGL context creation.

Comment: `glewInit()` is kinda important too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net). It will not directly solve your problem, but many (potentially related) problems with respect to using OpenGL extensions on Windows.

Comment: Is there no way to switch from VOBs to the function pipeline depending on the available driver? An API?

Comment: Those are separate things. VBOs are a way to store geometry so it can be accessed efficiently during rendering. You can store your geometry in VBOs and use fixed-function lighting, and you can use glVertex* etc. and use GLSL lighting.

Comment: thx for that. I'll try my best to combine it somehow: theory of VBOs and GLSL and the practical part of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

See if your platform supports OpenGL ES 2.0. This has virtually become the standard for modern desktops. If so use OpenGL ES 2.0.

Also you might be able to find a lot of the functionality that you require in OpenGL extensions. See what extensions are available on your platform and note that function names may differ from the later standard names (eg glBindFramebuffer_EXT)